# Remix is not loading all the methods of my SmartContract

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm very new to ERC20, ERC1155, SmartContracts, Remix, etc, so please forgive me if my question is quite stupid.
I've created an RC1155 SmartContract in Remix, with several methods.
When I publish it on the blockchain I obviously can immediately see all its methods in the left pane.
Let's say that after a couple of day I'd like to reload my SmartContract in Remix, so

- I open my workspace
- I recompile the same contract
- I move to same blockcain (I'm actually using Rinkeby)
- I reload the SmartContract from its address

=> result: I can see its adress in the left pane, but I just can see a couple of default methods (none of mine)
Why?
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: could you post the code and a pic of what you're seeing?
is the visibility of the functions you're not seeing external or public?
also, Remix can bug out at times and things not show. A refresh is worth a shot if the visibility is correct

Comment: You're totally right, Remix can bug! I've refreshed (again) the webpage, and repeated all the steps, and now I can see all the methods!

Comment: I've followed a tutorial and most of my new function are "external", but reading on the Solidity docs I guess that this kind of func should be available only if called by another contract... Well,I'm a bit confused, why them should'nt be public? or at least private?

Comment: public might use more gas and also, if it's not intended for internal use, leave more opportunity for a security issue by have a more permissive view than is required. It's common to have function that are only intended for use by an external caller. It doesn't have to be another smart contract, it could be your fronted website or suchlike

Comment: Many thanks! I have a lot to learn...